# Contar elementos pares de un array con recursividad

Tags: java, java-8

Me piden un programa que dada una lista cuente la cantidad de pares que hay, utilizando recursivad.
Hice el codigo pero no me recorre la lista, sino que me cuenta la primera posicion (donde el nro  es par) y me aumenta el contador a 1 y se termina.

```
public class Recur {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] vector = {8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 9};
    System.out.println("Hay " + suma(vector, 0, 0) + " nros pares");
}


public static int suma(int [] x,  int pos, int cont ) {
    if (pos==x.length) {
        return -1;
    }if(x[pos]%2==0) {
        cont++;
    }else {
        return suma(x, pos+1, cont);
    }
    return cont;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solo tienes tres premisas:

- Si la posición es igual a la longitud de la lista, significa se ha llegado al final y debes devolver el conteo.
- Si el número actual es par, incrementa el contador.
- En cualquier otro caso, vuelves a llamar a la función con la siguiente posición.

Esto, en código, luce:

```
public static int suma(int[] x, int pos, int cont) {
    if (pos == x.length) {
        return cont;
    }

    if (x[pos] % 2 == 0) {
        cont++;
    }
    return suma( x, pos + 1, cont );
}
```